# ¿Como puedo ajustar mi Expresion Regular para que no acepte 2 o más espacios en blanco juntos?

Tags: html5, regex

Actualmente manejo esta expresión regular para no aceptar caracteres especiales y segun yo funcionaba para no dejar escribir espacios juntos pero no trabaja bien, porque si tecleo 2, 3 espacios o más, acepta los puros espacios.

```
pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$"

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="empresa" placeholder="ej: Estoy interesado en..." name="empresa" minlength="5" maxlength="50" required pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se llama **clase de caracteres** a la estructura `[`..`]` que coincide con 1 caracter.

`[a-zA-Z0-9 ]` coincide con 1 caracter, cualquiera de los que están incluidos (alfanuméricos o espacios).

`[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*` coincide con 0 o más alfanuméricos o espacios... Claramente puede coincidir con espacios consecutivos.

#### Sin espacios consecutivos

Tenemos que generar un patrón que desarrolle el orden de caracteres para que cada vez que coincida con un espacio, exija un alfanumérico a continuación.

**Mínimo 1 caracter**:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?: [a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$
```

donde primero exige 1 o más `[a-zA-Z0-9]` (espacios no incluidos), y con `(?:`..`)*` estamos diciendo que repita 0 o más veces lo que está adentro del paréntesis:  `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` un espacio seguido de 1 o más alfanuméricos.

**También aceptando textos vacíos**:

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?: [a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)?$
```